# Click checkbox save to database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

GoodDay Masters!

I have a survey webpage answerable by YES or NO (CheckBox).

I want to count surveys by clicking CheckBox and save it into the database.
this is my codes...

```
  <label> Did you find this helpful? </label>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="yes">YES</input>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="no">NO</input>
    <?php 
    $fieldname = $_GET['question'];
    if($fieldname == 'YES' ){
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET YES = YES + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
    }else{
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET NO = NO + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
    }
?>
```

However I encounter error "Notice: Undefined index: question"

Should I use javascript or ajax? or I just mixed my codings? so what is wrong on my codes?

How can I trigger this code to update my database??

Comment: Yes +1? What's the result of that?

Comment: use AJAX, on checkbox click-> hit event for update ur DB..

Comment: @loko to add 1 when checkBox YES clicked

Comment: Sir.@Ashish sorry but how to use AJAX on this?

Comment: Why do you use two checkboxes for a YES/NO question ? Isn't one enough ?

Comment: Doesn't that give the value "Yes" +1 in your database, which cant be done? You are setting the column yes to yes+1 where .... = ....?

Comment: @Theox One for YES and the other one for NO... It must be two

Comment: From a user experience point of view, this is very confusing. You should replace the checkboxes with radio-buttons, so only one option is clickable.

Comment: I agree with Shahar, either use Radio buttons, or only one checkbox. Currently, an user can answer both "yes" AND "no" to your question.

Comment: Why do you use two different name ( question and question1) for getting one answer?

Comment: @Shahar how can I trigger this code to update my database??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this code. Please write you php code into any function and call that function into ajax request.

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="question" name="question" value="yes" onclick="get_checbox_data();">YES</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="question1" name="question1" value="no" onclick="get_checbox_data();">NO</input>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_checbox_data(){

  var ans = 'no';
        if ($('#question').is(':checked')) {
            ans = 'yes';
        }else if ($('#question1').is(':checked')) {
              ans = 'no';
        }
            $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "SITE_URL/save_checkbox_data",                    
          data:{'question':ans},                 
          success: function (data) {

          }
     });

    }</script>     

Edited:  In php file create function named save_checkbox_data like:    

function save_checkbox_data()
{
    if(isset($_POST['question']) && $_POST['question'] != '')
    {
        $fieldname = $_POST['question'];
        if($fieldname == 'YES' ){
            mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET YES = YES + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
        }else{
            mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET NO = NO + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
        }
    }
}
```

Best Of Luck

Comment: you may also want to disable the checkboxes afterwards or jump to another page. Otherwise I could just keep clicking yes.

Comment: @jagruti Where i should insert my mssql_query code? and what did you mean by "URL of your functions"??

Comment: @Waygood Sir where should I insert my mssql_query? and how to call this functions!

Comment: Change 'Url of your function' to /ajax/save_data.php and then put your php update code in there. (or whatever filename you want). then either check for $_POST['question'] etc.. or change `type="POST",` to `type="GET",`

Comment: @jagruti can you please complete this step of how to implement this AJAX. pardon me becuz I have no Idea on AJAX

Comment: @Waygood Sir should I create a .js file and paste this code on that file?

Comment: not unless you can run database queries in javascript. Ajax will send data to the PHP script, which does the DB update.

Comment: URL of your functions means Path of your function where it is. like     http://localhost/testapp/file_name/function_name

Answer (score 2):

The undefined index error is coming over here

```
$fieldname = $_GET['question'];
```

if you change you code like this notice should not come

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['question'])) { 
    $fieldname = $_GET['question'];
    if($fieldname == 'YES' ){
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET YES = YES + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
    }else{
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET NO = NO + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 But together with @Shahar suggestion of radio buttons will be a full answer.

Comment: @Maz Thank you sir! however how should I create a trigger that when user click the checkbox the script update will generate or the webpage will refresh?. because when I clicked the checkbox nothing happen.

Comment: p.s. This also doesn't automatically update the NO when the page loads. ie $_GET['question'] is not set, so null=='YES', which is false, so OP's code does the ELSE part.

Comment: see @jagruti ajax answer

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should send secured or non-bookmarkable data using *POST* instead *GET* method.
Make sure your form radio buttons are valid and have the same name to group them. 
**The HTML**:

```
<form id="myform" action="form_process.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>Did you find this helpful? </label>
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="1" />YES
    <input type="radio" name="question" value="0" />NO
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
 </div>
</form>
```

**The PHP** form_process.php example:

```
<?php
    // Include your database connection code

    if (isset($_POST[question])) {
    // If checkbox was chosen...
        $fieldname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['question'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    }

    if ($fieldname == TRUE){
        // Code to run when 'YES' selected
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET YES = YES + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
    } else if ($fieldname == FALSE) {
        // Code to run when 'NO' selected
        mssql_query("update TBL_SURVEY SET NO = NO + 1 WHERE adddate = (SELECT max(adddate) FROM TBL_SURVEY)");
    } else {
        // Data was not validated correctly
    }
?>
```

I did not test this code, but this is the general idea. Make sure you test your queries and check that the data is saved correctly (No database schema, code or information was provided).